# Software need for video editing

Tags: video-editing, windows-xp

I am looking for a software for removing clips of particular start time to a particular end time in a video. Is there any software which provides this facility?

I need the software for Windows XP & GUI version of the software is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/products/dvd/Free-Video-Dub.htm . it isn't very precise but it is usefull.